# Bootstrap accordion collapsible and checkbox change interference

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Have this issue that boggles my mind. I have a checkbox inside an accordion group. My procedure is when pressing the checkbox inside the accordion group, it expands the body of that accordion group, and `show()` another button somewhere else.

The problem is when pressing two checkboxes, the button show up and hide really fast. My assumption is the click event bubbles somewhere and I am not able to grab it there and shut it up for good!

My HTML

```
<div class="accordion span5" id="info-accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group" data-pid="71" data-pweight="2">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <input type="checkbox" class="tier-check" value="17">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-17">2013-07-10 14:21:03</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-17" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Naware is a village in the Bassar Prefecture in the Kara Region of north-western Togo. and add some more content. This is the old one. should show in the info now. To be save really.

            This text should be improved.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group" data-pid="71" data-pweight="2">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <input type="checkbox" class="tier-check" value="21">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-21">2013-07-10 14:20:39</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-21" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Naware is a village in the Bassar Prefecture in the Kara Region of north-western Togo. and add some more content. This is the old one. should show in the info now. To be save really.

            This text should be improved.


            This is new text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group" data-pid="71" data-pweight="2">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <input type="checkbox" class="tier-check" value="18">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-18">2013-07-10 14:07:53</a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-18" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Naware is no more
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript is

```
//hide them all
var orgchk = $('.tier-check:checkbox').not(':checked');

orgchk.each(function(i) { 
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

    var cllps = $('#collapse-' + $(this).val() ); 
    if ( cllps.hasClass('in') );
            cllps.collapse('toggle');
});

//when only one checkbox is selected, show it
var chkbx = $('.tier-check:checkbox:checked');
$('#collapse-' + chkbx.val() ).collapse('show');

if ( chkbx.length != 0 )
         $tier_btn.fadeIn();
else
         $tier_btn.fadeOut();
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nuE2c/ still tailoring it towards my case

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using this. It seems it stops event propagation when jQuery stopPropogation() and StopImmediatePropagation() didn't work for me

```
$('#accordion').on('hidden',function(e) {
            return false;//stopping propagation
    });
```